# Input type color not working in IE 11

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer-11, color-picker

HTML-5 color type is not working in IE 11 browser and working in chrome browser as i expect.
Kindly check this in both chrome browser and IE-11, give me your suggestion, Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="col-sm-8 cngcolor">
                                <input type="color" id="background" name="background" value="#ffffff" list="colors" class="input-xs show-tick ng-pristine selectpicker form-control">
                                <datalist id="colors">
                                    <option>#ffffff</option>
                                    <option>#ff0000</option>
                                    <option>#000000</option>
                                </datalist>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

The color input is not supported in IE11 - [check out this great page](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-color).

**Update**

An alternative solution would be to use a polyfill - e.g. [Spectrum](https://github.com/bgrins/spectrum) (however, I have not tried this one yet).

Comment: Ok fine, Can you give me any other suggestion.

Comment: I would search for a color picker polyfill for IE11 - haven't used one by myself but I am sure you will be able to find a few of them - e.g. [Spectrum](https://github.com/bgrins/spectrum)

Answer (score 0):

[Can I use...: Color input type](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-color) IE doesn't support this input type.

Comment: Can you give me any other suggestion to include colorpicker in IE-11

Answer (score 0):

for anyone encountering this question, this is the polyfill for IE support
https://github.com/jonstipe/color-polyfill

Answer (score 0):

This is works for me, I added script and link in html.
Credits to this link : https://github.com/bgrins/spectrum
Using spectrum with a CDN
CDN provided by cdnjs

"
"

Comment: This seems to be more like a comment but not an answer. Please see Stack Overflow help [How to answer section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)